# Why has the author used the following matrices for the following standardisation?

Tags: r, statistics, normalization, data-science

Can somebody tell me why this author has used the following code in their normalisation.

The first line appears fine to me they have standardised the training set by the following formula;

> (x - mean(x)) / std(x)

However the second line and third line (validation and test) they have used the train mean (trainme) and train standard deviation (trainstd). Should they not have used the validation mean (validationme) and validation standard deviation (validationstd) along with the test mean and test standard deviation?

[image]

You can also view the page from the book at the following link [(page 173)](https://books.google.es/books?id=erkrDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=direction%3C-%09data.frame(matrix(NA,dim(dji)%5B1%5D,1))&source=bl&ots=BYgJgm4Xrt&sig=fti3u_qklFVaY_XgsSLlumi3fvI&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX7t7qkpvXAhVEuRoKHX_tDpgQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

What the authors are doing is reasonable and it's what is conventionally done. The idea is that the same normalization is applied to all inputs. This is essentially allocating some new parameters (offset and scale) and estimating them from the training data. In that scheme, if the value 100 is input, then the normalized value is (100 - offset)/scale, no matter where (training, testing, whatever) that 100 came from.

I guess one can also make an argument that the offset and scale should be context dependent in the sense that if you are given a set of data and for some reason the offset and scale are very different from the original training data, maybe what's important is how big each value is relative to the others in the same data set. E.g. maybe you should treat 200 the same as 100, if the scale is twice as big in the data set containing 200.

Whether that data-dependent scaling is reasonable would have to be decided case by case. I don't remember ever having seen it, but it's plausible that it could be the right thing to do in some cases.

By the way, you'll get more interest in general statistical questions at stats.stackexchange.com and/or datascience.stackexchange.com.